# Distribute iphone app to existing customers

Tags: ipad, app-store

Does anyone know if there is an alternative to the developer enterprise option for app development?

We are considering developing an app but I don't am not sure if would get approved via the App Store because the reach may not be large enough?

The app would show various data that we collect for our customers, therefore it is only really relevant to our existing customers

Would apple allow such an app on the App Store?

I don't think the enterprise package would be applicable because that appears to be targeted for people in our organisation we want to be able to distribute apps to our customers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in what you described that would violate the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (Login required).

Also, for Apple to reject an app because it was only useful to a particular company's customers would go against the precedent they've set by accepting apps for banks, credit cards, brokerage accounts, Netflix, Carbonite, etc.

So would Apple reject you on that basis? Almost certainly not, but really the only way to be absolutely sure is to submit the app and find out.

---

Here are a few of the guidelines about functionality that may or may not apply to you here, in case you cannot access the full list:

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may
>   be rejected
>
> **2.13** Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be rejected
>
> **2.22** Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected

From what I understand, none of these apply to your situation.

Comment: Thanks we will have a smaller user base in terms of companies, that access the app but as you say, this does not appear to breach the terms, we would just need to decide which program to use, the business one or the cheaper one.